# How to convert Array in C++ to Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I convert this C++ code

```
for(int i=0; i<3; ++i){
   array[i][0]=i*4+0;
   array[i][1]=i*4+1;
   array[i][2]=i*4+2;
   array[i][3]=i*4+3;}
```

to Python ?

---

When your IDE says `xrange` is **an undefined function**,please look at @ThiefMaste'comments :

Just because your IDE says something is not defined, it doesn't mean it's not defined. However, if you are using Python3 it is not defined since it was renamed to range (and the original, non-iterator range was removed)

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
In [3]: [[i*4+j for j in xrange(4)] for i in xrange(3)]
Out[3]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

Comment: the second xrange should be xrange(3) since his loop is `<3`, not `<=3`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Thanks, typo fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = []
for i in range(3):
    list.append([i*4, i*4+1, i*4+2, i*4+3])
```

or to be more exact (in case the list is not empty before):

```
for i in range(3):
    list[i] = [i*4, i*4+1, i*4+2, i*4+3]
```

and a more pythonic approach to generate the 4 elements would be:

```
[i*4+n for n in range(4)]
```

Comment: Just because your IDE says something is not defined, it doesn't mean it's not defined. However, if you are using Python3 it *is* not defined since it was renamed to `range` (and the original, non-iterator `range` was removed)

Comment: @roccia: Would you please stop deleting your comments after the question asked in them has been answered?!

Comment: @ThiefMaster:o..o ~  I was trying to make the question more clearly, so I deleted the comments..

Comment: but the problem is that the following reader can't read your comment so they will have hard time to understand the answer

Comment: ...I will add the question in original question..